# Full-text upgrade option to select during SQL Server in-place upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, upgrade

What Full-text upgrade option should be selected ideally while doing SQL Server in-place upgrade? The Full-text Upgrade screen provides three Full-Text upgrade options (import, rebuild and reset). What should be selected ideally and what are the pros and cons of each option? Also how do I know if full text is currently used or not?

Comment: [It depends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142490.aspx), choose whichever makes the most sense for you. You can query to see if there are any in use: `select * from sys.fulltext_indexes`

Comment: Ignore the following, MS have changed things up since I last used FTI. It always returns true on user databases   *You can check to see if Full Text Indexing is enabled on a database using select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'IsFulltextEnabled'). Just replace master with the DB you want to check.